# 301 redirect parameters without index.php in HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

After reading not too few threds in here and testing, I still haven't found a solution for some messy URL's I want to redirect.

Example 1:
I want to redirect the following URL:

```
www.mysite.co.il/binyanei/minisite/?ref=glob_AdvertisingArticle
```

to

```
www.mysite.co.il/
```

I found this syntax, but it's only relevant for URL's with index.php and it's just doesn't work for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1
RewriteRule ^sub-dir/index\.php$ /path-to-new-location/? [L,R=301]
```

Redirect one clean URL to a new clean URL